# Accessing React-Native navigation without props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I made a little helper component

```
 const NavHelper = ({ navigation, dest }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(`${dest}`)}>
      <Text>Go to {dest}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

It works by sending navigation as a prop.

```
<NavHelper navigation={navigation} dest="List" />
```

But since this component will always use navigation it would be nice if I could access navigation without having to send it as a prop to avoid repetition.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/

On the homepage it says you can do this by by using

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const NavHelper = ({ dest }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(`${dest}`)}>
      <Text>Go to {dest} Demo</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

But when I try this approach in my component, the emulator says it can't find a navigator object.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution, turns out there are multiple versions of react-navigation and I was looking at the documentation for 5.x while using 4.x.

I was supposed to use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/connecting-navigation-prop